# React Native: Is there anyway to check if image is already cached based on URI?

Tags: react-native

If user is not on WiFi, then image should be checked in cache if it is there, then there shouldn't be any prompt to download image else user should be given on option to download image!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the urls which are accessed to the local database, 
And then when the user is not on wifi then read the databade (save it as key and value so you can check in o(1) and check if the key is exist)

Comment: No such thing available in react native? I Mean anything that react-native's image component can handle itself!

Comment: Not an answer really, it makes no sense